# React Rendering twice in Private Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When I run console.log in my render component, it appear twice in the chrome dev inspector. This only happen in the private routes.

I have tried messing around the Router in Switch, but nothing doesn't work

App.js**********

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PrivateRoute path="/user" component={Layout} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/user/dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/user/profile" component={ProfilePage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/user/vehicles" component={VehiclesPage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/user/routes" component={RoutesPage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/user/sessions" component={SessionsPage} />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={RealmForm} /> //login page redirect to "/user/dashboard"
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default (App);
```

index.js *********

```js
ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

PrivateRoute.js**********

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";



class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  state = {
    authenticated: false
  };

  render() {

    }

    const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          authenticated ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: { from: this.props.location }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withKeycloak(PrivateRoute);
```

I just want to console anything in the render component once. I think it is related to the way I set up the routes, but I am not sure.

Comment: you said the console.log appears twice, could you be more precise, is it for a special route path or for all the routes ?

Comment: What is a private route? You need to supply more information if you want help with this. We can't even see what you are trying to console log.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Private route is used for auth, allowing only user authenticated to have access to those quotes, I will add the code above.  If I log any console from the private route, I will see the console come twice

Comment: @davirk21, On initial launch of the App, you should see console in Private Route for 6 times, because you are trying to render the component 6 times. When you try to navigate to Private Route you shouldn't see the log. However can you refactor your code in PrivateRoute component ..  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { authenticated : false};
  }

Comment: @davirk21, I see that you are wrapping PrivateRoute with higher order component keyCloak, do you really need that ? One possible reason maybe that your higher order component could be re-rendering ?

Comment: @YugandharPathi, I did remove the HOC and updated the state. When I invoke a console.log in Vehicle Page. I receive a call stack as such 
//Private route console.log ( x4)
//console.log("here") in vehicle page
//Private route console.log( x2)
//console.log("here") in vehicle page

Answer (score 2):

Note sure what PrivateRoute component does, but if that uses Route somewhere inside, you should use [exact](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#exact-bool) property for path="/user", which can be passed to the PrivateRoute component.

```
<PrivateRoute path="/user" exact component={ Layout } />
```

Comment: Private route is used for auth, allowing only user authenticated to have access to those ruotes, I will add the code above. If I log any console from the private route, I will see the console come twice

Comment: unfortunately adding exact to the private route did not fix this problem. I am still seeing any console.log being logged twice